# Checking parallel_for loop syntax

Tags: c++, performance, syntax

I've been asked by a friend to help them improve the performance of their code, I'm not very well versed in C++, with most of my training in Java. The program is designed to find optimal values for a set of data, and uses a fairly blunt "try everything" method, which obviously is fairly slow to run. My solution was to replace the outer most loop of the main process.

However: I am very unfamiliar with this tool, as I've never used it before, and can't tell if I've successfully replicated the original loop's behavior with the new one I've written. Or even if my parameters are correctly formatted. I've searched a good few times but can't seem to find a concise explanation for how to format these as opposed to "normal" for loops.

Additional inclusions (obviously):

```
include "tbb/parallel_for.h"
```

The original loop:

```
for(alpha=30; alpha < 101; alpha= alpha+4) {
```

The new one:

```
parallel_for (alpha(30); 101; & {
```

The example I'm working from:

- example:

  ```
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
  ```
- Example:

  ```
  parallel_for (size_t(0), size, [&](size_t i)
  ```

Sadly; I can't simply test the code, since I haven't the entire program, merely the .cpp file.

Comment: "been asked by a friend to help them improve the performance of their code, I'm not very well versed in C++" - Sounds to me like they should get someone else to review their code then.

Comment: "I can't simply test the code, since I haven't the entire program, merely the .cpp file" - Why bother trying at all then? You don't have everything needed to do the job, so don't even try.

Comment: Pursuing an alternative algorithm to "try everything" (btw, that's commonly called "brute force"), would probably be more advantageous in the long run. Regardless, using parallel-for will only succeed in reducing the perceived workload from W to W/n, where n is the number of sub-tasks capable of concurrent execution, and even that only assuming you have `n` freely available concurrent resources (e.g. processors, memory, whatever) available. The moment you introduce shared state that train starts to depart the rails quickly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Those were quite literally the first things i said to him actually.

Comment: @WhozCraig Quite literally the first observation I made upon reviewing his code (he isn't a trained programmer), is that the "brute force" method employed is extremely inefficient, and is where most of the program's "work" is currently being spent.  But; he has an algorithm he wants to keep intact, so that's what I've got to work around.  Fortunately; raw number of processors shouldn't be an issue, hence my attempted parallel for solution.

Comment: Sure. So long as it's crystal clear that an algorithm with geometric or exponential asymptotic complexity doesn't really get any better with a parallel algorithm. I.e. O(N^2)/k where k is constant (in this case core count) is still ultimately O(n^2). For specific cases of reasonably small n it can *help*, but ultimately as n grows, that k becomes less and less helpful.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm aware; once again, one of the first things I explained upon seeing the code was "this scales terribly", but that's what I've got to work with without rebuilding this thing from the ground up.  So; in that case, the difference between it sitting and running for an hour and a half, to it sitting and running for an hour instead is a net benefit.